# Running from Eclipse can not find tld-file, but running in jar it works

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot, taglib

After having read [Spring Boot with JSPs in Executable Jars](http://hillert.blogspot.lu/2016/03/spring-boot-with-jsp-in-executable-jar.html), I converted a Spring Boot project from being packaged as `war`, to `jar`.

While everything works fine as long as the project is running as a jar, it does not work when I start the main-class in Eclipse. The project starts, but when I access it I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp (line: 6, column: 2)
The absolute uri: http://my.project/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml
or the jar files deployed with this application
```

The tld-file resides in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/mytags.tld`, see this excerpt:

```
<tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
<short-name>My Tag library</short-name>
<uri>http://my.project/tags</uri>
<display-name></display-name>
<small-icon></small-icon>
<large-icon></large-icon>
<description></description>
```

The functions and tags exist in my project as source-files, so they are in the classpath and accessible to Eclipse.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try to add your TLDs to `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF`? Handling of Taglibs seems finicky across servlet containers (when using executable jars) and admittedly I have not used custom taglibs in a while. In my experience so far, though, `META-INF/resources/WEB-INF` behaves identical to war deployments (with Tomcat).

The following discussion also might be useful:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/522567/java-Web-Component-OCEJWCD/certification/location-TLDs

Comment: Your suggestion, which sounds logical, works perfectly ... :-) Thank you

Comment: In addition to the TLDs, you will also have to move any * .tag files to the `WEB-INF/tags` folder for it to work.